# Check if field exists in json type column PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

How do you check if a `json` field in Postgres has a certain element?

I have tried with `json->>'attribute' is not null` and doesn't work.

Answer (score 111):

use `->`:

```
where (json->'attribute') is not null
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the error `cannot extract element from a scalar`

Comment: @Chad you probably have to cast your content to the right type doing `where (myfield::json->'attribute') is not null`.

Comment: FYI The parens aren't necessary.

Comment: exists != is not null

Comment: @brendan yes, you're right. But I didn't claim that it is.

Comment: @Brendan `column->'attribute'` will only yield null if the json path does not exist. `column->>'attribute'` will give null if it does not exist, *or* if it does exist and the value is null, e.g. `column = '{"attribute":null}'`.

Answer (score 54):

While [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19426953/4632019) works. It is better to use special operator [`?`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html):

```
WHERE your_column_name::jsonb ? 'attribute'
```

**NOTE**: Only for `jsonb` type.

Comment: If the column is already type jsonb, then the cast is unnecessary. For jsonb columns this is a cleaner answer.

Comment: that's indeed much cleaner for jsonb

Comment: Note the `?` operator only works for top-level attributes. If you want to check if a path exists lower down in the json structure, do `.. where column->'foo'->'bar'->'baz' is not null`, as per Roman's answer.

Comment: The expression `.. WHERE column->'foo'->'bar'->'baz' IS NOT NULL` doesn't work at least in Postgres 9.4, you need to surround  the left part with `( )`, so to make the expression works: `.. WHERE (column->'foo'->'bar'->'baz') IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I'd love to know why it's better to use the `?` operator than the `->` operator suggested in @RomanPekar's solution

Comment: @RocketAppliances: When you use `->` it will check existing of value for`your_column_name.attribute`, but `?` will check existing of `attribute`. That is. For example: `obj.field IS NULL` will return  `true`, but `obj ? 'field'` will return `false`

Answer (score 1):

This also works if your_column_name is **json** type:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE your_column_name->>'attribute' is not NULL;
```