# What is the difference between `->>` and `->` in Postgres SQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

What is the difference between `->>` and `->` in SQL?

In this thread ([Check if field exists in json type column postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422233/check-if-field-exists-in-json-type-column-postgresql)), the answerer basically recommends using,

```
json->'attribute' is not null
```

instead of,

```
json->>'attribute' is not null
```

Why use a single arrow instead of a double arrow? In my limited experience, both do the same thing.

Comment: [Hail to the forgotten virtue of Reading The Fine Manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: The docs are lacking when it comes to how nulls are handled. See [@TmTron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58629370/165673). Also, it's strange that there's no operator that retrieves a JSON value in its native type.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

`->` returns json (or jsonb) and `->>` returns `text`:

```
with t (jo, ja) as (values
    ('{"a":"b"}'::jsonb,('[1,2]')::jsonb)
)
select
    pg_typeof(jo -> 'a'), pg_typeof(jo ->> 'a'),
    pg_typeof(ja -> 1), pg_typeof(ja ->> 1)
from t
;
 pg_typeof | pg_typeof | pg_typeof | pg_typeof 
-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------
 jsonb     | text      | jsonb     | text
```

Comment: You probably mean that the first operator returns `jsonb` (and not `json(b)`).

Comment: @AlexanderFarber I mean it can return both json and jsonb hence the parenthesis

Comment: I clarified the `json(b)` phrasing

Answer (score 72):

PostgreSQL provides two native operators `->` and `->>` to help you query JSON data.

The operator `->` returns JSON object field as JSON.
The operator `->>` returns JSON object field as text.

The following query uses operator `->` to get all customers in form of JSON:

```sql
SELECT
 info -> 'customer' AS customer
FROM
 orders;
```

```
customer
--------
"John Doe"
"Lily Bush"
"Josh William"
"Mary Clark"
```

And the following query uses operator `->>` to get all customers in form of text:

```sql
SELECT
 info ->> 'customer' AS customer
FROM
 orders;
```

```
customer
--------
John Doe
Lily Bush
Josh William
Mary Clark
```

You can see more details in the link below
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/

Answer (score 42):

Postgres offers 2 operators to get a JSON member:

- the arrow operator: `->` returns type JSON or JSONB
- the double arrow operator: `->>` returns type text

We must also understand that we now have 2 different kinds of **null**:

- ***(null)*** postgres null type
- **null** json/b null type

I created an example on [jsfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/00fa6d/4)

Let's create a simple table with a JSONB field:

```
create table json_test (
  id integer,
  val JSONB
);
```

and insert some test-data:

```
INSERT INTO json_test (id, val) values
(1, jsonb_build_object('member', null)),
(2, jsonb_build_object('member', 12)),
(3, null);
```

Output as we see it in sqlfiddle:

```
id  | val
----+-----------------
 1  | {"member": null}
 2  | {"member": 12}
 3  | (null)
```

Notes:

1. contains a JSONB object and the only field `member` is **null**
2. contains a JSONB object and the only field `member` has the numeric value `12`
3. is ***(null)***: i.e. the whole column is ***(null)*** and does not contain a JSONB object at all

To better understand the differences, let's look at the types and null-checks:

```
SELECT id,
  val -> 'member'  as arrow,
  pg_typeof(val -> 'member')  as arrow_pg_type,
  val -> 'member' IS NULL as arrow_is_null,
  val ->> 'member' as dbl_arrow,
  pg_typeof(val ->> 'member')  as dbl_arrow_pg_type,
  val ->> 'member' IS NULL as dbl_arrow_is_null,
  CASE WHEN jsonb_typeof(val -> 'member') = 'null' THEN true ELSE false END as is_json_null
from json_test;
```

Output:

| id | arrow | arrow_pg_type | arrow_is_null | dbl_arrow | dbl_arrow_pg_type | dbl_arrow_is_null | is_json_null |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | jsonb | false | (null) | text | true | true |
| 2 | 12 | jsonb | false | 12 | text | false | false |
| 3 | (null) | jsonb | true | (null) | text | true | false |

Notes:

- for `{"member": null}`:

  - `val -> 'member' IS NULL` is **false**
  - `val ->> 'member' IS NULL` is true
- `is_json_null` can be used to get **only** the json-**null** condition

Comment: Thanks for being through and clear! @TmTron

Answer (score 15):

The single-arrow `->` is for **directly accessing the JSON**.

The double-arrow `->>` is for **accessing *and* converting**.

(As has been answered here a few times.)

The key to *remembering* this is that:

- **`->`** the *shorter* arrow is for doing less work: it does a single thing:  **one arrow, one thing**: just access JSON
- **`->>`** the *longer* arrow is more work for you to type and more work for postgres to do: **two arrows, two things**: access JSON *and* convert it to text