# what is the difference between -> and => when connecting to postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I noticed that there are two modes that am seeing in postgresql whenever I tried to connect. I'm new to this db engine. so there were two. let's say I have a database named "test"

what's the difference between

```
test->
```

and

```
test=>
```

in the terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear to me , may be I got it wrong .

=> Means , you are good to go for new command.

Where as

-> means the continuation of the active command.

You can check this ask ubuntu link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/806477/difference-between-postgres-and-postgres

Now there is another ->> and ->

The operator -> returns JSON object field as JSON. The operator ->> returns JSON object field as text.

You can check this link : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777535/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-postgres-sql#:~:text=3%20Answers&text=PostgreSQL%20provides%20two%20native%20operators,JSON%20object%20field%20as%20text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777535/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-postgres-sql#:%7E:text=3%20Answers&text=PostgreSQL%20provides%20two%20native%20operators,JSON%20object%20field%20as%20text).

Feel free to reply or comment , if I understood the question wrong.

Comment: the first part of your comment is what am trying to find out

Comment: If you liked that , accept it as an answer or upvote it  . It will help me a lot . Thanks