# How to add a SQLAlchemy BTREE index on a JSONB column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a model definition:

```
class Customer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    clientid = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    custcontext_json = db.Column(JSONB, default=lambda: {})  
    
    __table_args__ = (db.Index('customer_idx_gin1', custcontext_json, postgresql_using="gin"),)
```

I want to add an btree index that will be added with next alembic migration:

```
 create index customer_idx_json1 on customer using btree((custcontext_json->'foo'->'bar'));
```

I went through the docs but I was not able to put it together for a btree on JSONB. Can anybody pls provide some pointers?

Comment: Note that you can't create a btree index on a JSON(B) value. So your index expression should extract the content as text: `(custcontext_json->'foo'->>'bar')`

Comment: What are the datatypes that you are using for `bar`. You also probably need to cast the value. And the index in `__table_args__` is specified with `gin` and the index example uses `btree`.

Comment: @rfkortekaas The index in `__table_args__` is just an example thats works for a `gin` index. I have trouble finding the correct syntax for adding a `btree` index the same way.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name has this correct. It's possible to btree nested values [(reference)](https://bitnine.net/blog-postgresql/postgresql-internals-jsonb-type-and-its-indexes/) but you will need to access via the text operator `->>`, not the json traverse operator `->` [(reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777535/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-postgres-sql)