# Spring Boot postgres native query hstore key value query

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to query a hstore entry by key/value pair provided to my query.

```
@Query(value = "select * from result x where x.tenant_id = ?1 AND x.deleted != true AND x.metadata ->> ?2 = ?3", nativeQuery = true)
```

Doesnt seem to work. The error I am getting:

**Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: hstore ->> character varying**

Is there a trick or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE) there is no operator `->>` only `->`

Comment: Your comment is incorrect. See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777535/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-postgres-sql

Comment: But yes, using -> instead of ->> with variable placeholders works in my case. Where AND x.metadata ->> 'X' = 'Y' works as well

Comment: The `->>` operator is defined for JSON and JSONB, not for HSTORE

Comment: Correct - that was the issue. Thanks!