# Query nested jsonb object supabase

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, supabase

I have a Contacts table in Supabase with a 'basics' column that is of type jsonb.

The 'basics' jsonb looks like this :

```
{
  "id": "f760017a-7adb-437c-8b5c-4e1f914a0339",
  "avatar": "",
  "status": "active",
  "company": "",
  "channels": {
    "239455a5-9d0b-48d7-8ef2-8310fdcc5e73": {
      "id": "239455a5-9d0b-48d7-8ef2-8310fdcc5e73",
      "label": "Instagram",
      "value": "",
      "channelKey": "social",
      "channelType": "Social",
      "isMessageChannel": false
    },
    "abbde327-d5bd-4428-b980-0311ae574d91": {
      "id": "abbde327-d5bd-4428-b980-0311ae574d91",
      "label": "Personal",
      "value": "",
      "channelKey": "email",
      "channelType": "Email",
      "isMessageChannel": false
    },
    "cb783d57-d9b3-4e9f-a708-3f115a154f23": {
      "id": "cb783d57-d9b3-4e9f-a708-3f115a154f23",
      "label": "Mobile",
      "value": "3335557777",
      "channelKey": "sms",
      "channelType": "Phone",
      "isMessageChannel": true
    }
  },
  "lastName": "Roberts",
  "addresses": {},
  "firstName": "Freddie"
}
```

I need to find a contact based on their phone number.

I tried this but it fails.

```
const { data: contacts, error: _err } = await supabaseClient
            .from('contacts')
            .select('*')
            .contains('basics->channels->value', '3335557777')
```

Is anyone able to help with matching this nested value?

Thanks!!

Eric

Comment: is this (https://dbfiddle.uk/KoqFoFLt) ok for you?

Comment: @jian thank you, that definitely works in your example. Are you familiar with supabase and the syntax for making that selection form the font-end?

Comment: I am not  familiar with supabase.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the `value` with a double arrow like this: `->>value`

```
const { data: contacts, error: _err } = await supabaseClient
            .from('contacts')
            .select('*')
            .contains('basics->channels->>value', '3335557777')
```

You can read more about it here: [What is the difference between `->>` and `->` in Postgres SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777535/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-postgres-sql)