# Sql update where for nested Json object

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma

I am trying to write an update query that updates any users that have a dog named "Mark", the table has a column named "additional_options" and it is a Json blob that looks like this

```
{
'dog_name': 'Mark'
}
```

Right now I have

```
update "Employees" e set country = "BR" where json_extract_path(e.additional_options, "dog_name") = "Mark"
```

I'm using this postgres functions found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html) to build this, but right now I'm getting an error

```
column "dog_name" does not exist
```

can anyone help me figure out why this isn't working?

Edit:
If it helps, I wrote this query using Prisma and it works

```
export const moveToBrazil = async(): Promise<Employee[]> => {
    await db.employees.updateMany({
        where: {
            additional_options: {
                path: ['dog_name'],
                equals: 'Ellie'
            }
        },
        data: {
            country: "BR"
        }
    });
    return db.employees.findMany({
        where: {
            additional_options: {
                path: ['dog_name'],
                equals: 'Ellie'
            }
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Postgres uses double quotes to escape reserved words or column names with spaces or such

Comment: Thats right, I have a new problem then, it doesn't know the type of 'dog_name'.
```
json_extract_path(jsonb, unknown) does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `->>` operator to get the `json` object field as text. Something like:

```
UPDATE "Employees" e SET country = 'BR' WHERE e.additional_options->>'dog_name' = 'Mark';
```

The `->>` operator gets the JSON object field ***as text***. If `additional_options` is a `jsonb` column and `dog_name` is a key in that JSON, `additional_options->>'dog_name'` gets the value of `dog_name` as text.

***[CODE DEMO](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3zsj9ubvj)***

[REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38777821/19090048)

Comment: This is the correct answer! Thank you for your help and your explanation, you're the best!