# Postgres check if value exists in a table's column

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, postgresql

How would I check to see if a value exists with name Dan in column sess  from a table called Table1 with 3 columns called id, sess, and timeD.

Sess type is JSON

```
Table1

id    sess                                         timeD
1     {"cookie":{expires:null}, "name": "Joey"}    12:30
2     {"cookie":{expires:null}, "name": "Dan"}      1:00
3     {"cookie":{expires:null}, "name": "Bob"}      1:20
```

Comment: @bca I'm checking to see if name has value Dan in the sess column.  I'm not checking if the column is null

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422233/check-if-field-exists-in-json-type-column-postgresql can perhaps help?

Comment: @jarlh I'm reading it but like how would you determine the name is Bob?

Comment: What is the column type of "sess"?

Comment: Generally you should provide the relevant schema (columns and types), indexes, postgres version, etc.

Comment: What kind of indexes exist?  Does this kind of query require scans?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the column type of `sess`.
If it's a string you can use a string match, e.g.

```sql
where sess like '%"name": "Dan"%'
```

If it's json you can query for values inside the json object using [JSON functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html), e.g.

```sql
where sess->>'name' = 'Bob'
```

Or if it's a string type but contains JSON you can parse the string to JSON then query on the JSON like:

```sql
where sess::json->>'name' = 'Bob'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the contains operator: `@>`

```
where sess @> '{"name": "Dan"}'
```

this assumes that `sess` is defined as a `jsonb` column (which it should be). If it's not, you need to cast it: `sess::jsonb @> ...`